# Central limit theorem for random variables with exactly a 2nd moment

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

Consider $X_m$ which are independent, identically distributed random variables which have moments exactly up to order $2$ and no higher. This can be done in numerous ways. One is the following: let $a_n$ be a sequence of positive numbers that goes to zero and let $b_n$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b_n}{a_n}$ converges. (For example, $a_n=1/n,b_n=2^{-n}$ does the job.) Let $f_n(x)=(2+a_n) 1_{[1,\infty)}(x) |x|^{-3-a_n}$. Then let $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b_n}{\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k} f_n(x)$. Then $f$ is a pdf of a r.v. which has no higher moments than the second (since each $f_n$ has exactly moments of order strictly less than $2+a_n$). The assumption about $b_n$ ensures that it actually does have a finite second moment. (In effect the trick here is $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty [1,2+a_n)=[1,2]$.)

Despite this somewhat pathological moment property, the classical central limit theorem still tells us that $\frac{\overline{X}_m-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{m}}$ converges in distribution to a $N(0,1)$ random variable. However, the most common quantitative estimates for the convergence rate, e.g. the Berry-Esseen theorem, require the existence of a moment higher than order $2$. What can be said about the convergence rate in cases like the one in the previous paragraph?

Answer (score 2):

The paper

Friedman, N.; Katz, Melvin; Koopmans, L. H. Convergence rates for the central limit theorem. Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. U.S.A. 56 1966 1062–1065.,

available [here](http://www.pnas.org/content/56/4/1062), seems to give something in this direction. The authors prove that for an i.i.d. sequence of centered random variables with unit variance and such that $\mathbb E\left[X_1^2\log\left(1+\left|X_1\right|\right)\right]< +\infty$, the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty }  \frac 1n\left|\mathbb P\left\{ \frac{S_n } { \sqrt n  }\leqslant x\right\} - \Phi(x)  \right|   $$
is convergent for any $x\in\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$, where $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ and $\Phi$ denotes the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal distribution.

However, we still have a little bit more than a finite second moment.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, for an i.i.d. sequence of centered random variables with unit variance, the authors show that the convergence of the series in your post is equivalent to the convergence of$$\sum_n\frac1n\left(E(X_1^2;|X_1|\geqslant\sqrt{n})+E(X_1;|X_1|\leqslant\sqrt{n})^2\right)$$ which seems to be equivalent (but I fail to understand why the authors do not mention this) to the finiteness of $$\sum_n\frac1nE(X_1^2;|X_1|\geqslant\sqrt{n})$$ or, even more simply, of $$E(X_1^2\log^+|X_1|).$$ (That the case $x=0$ is different, as Rosen's theorem shows, is notable.)

Comment: @Did You are right. I should have looked at the paper more carefully. It is an element of answer, but of course not a complete answer to the question.

Comment: We might be closer to a definitive answer than your comment makes believe since every square integrable random variable $Y$ is such that $E(u(Y)Y^2)$ is finite, for some well chosen function $u$ going to infinity at infinity.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful and relevant. It also seems to suggest that we might expect very little here. In particular, since the result excludes $x=0$, I would expect that it is not uniform in $x$. Additionally, the convergence of that sum is a rather mild property, for instance it is enough to have the difference being $O(\log(n)^{-1-\delta})$...

Comment: @Did It would be interesting to see if such a $u$ could be explicitly constructed in my example (answerers are free to choose $a_n,b_n$ as they see fit).

Comment: @Ian In full generality, pick $y_0=0$ and $(y_n)$ nondecreasing such that $E(Y^2;|Y|\geqslant y_n)\leqslant1/n^3$ for every $n\geqslant1$ and define $u(y)=n$ if $y_n\leqslant|y|<y_{n+1}$, then $u\to\infty$ at infinity and $E(Y^2u(Y))\leqslant\sum\limits_nE(Y^2u(Y);y_n\leqslant|Y|< y_{n+1})\leqslant\sum\limits_nnE(Y^2;y_n\leqslant|Y|< y_{n+1})\leqslant\sum\limits_nnE(Y^2;|Y|\geqslant y_{n})$ converges. In your $(a_n,b_n)$-case, I did not check whether this construction yields anything specific.